# Triggering mac autocorrect from Javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

Is there a way to trigger autocorrect in Safari programatically (instead of actually typing until a suggestion appears)?

I tried manipulating the value, but no correction is suggested, unlike the case when I manually type the exact same word. I even tried emulating that by adding characters one-by-one as a keyboard event, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete?

Comment: Whichever you mean, the answer is no.  These are OS-level functions; you have no access to them from within browser code.